# jquery ajax post error in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

i am using following code to publish Image on facebook

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos",
            data: {message: "",
                url: "my Image url",
                access_token: accessToken,
                format: "json"},
           dataType: "json",

              success: function(data){


               uploads(id);
            },
            error: function(data){alert("Failed! " + data.error);}
    });
```

This code works fine on Chrome, firefox and any other browser invented in the world
but it is not  working in Internet explorer. 
Whats wrong in this code??

Comment: Which version of IE? Check IE's Dev Tools console for errors as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is a cross-domain request. So use

```
 dataType: "jsonp",
```

set `jsonpCallback` to ajax config. That is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos",
    data: {
        message: "",
        url: "my Image url",
        access_token: accessToken,
        format: "json"
    },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'blah', // here
    success: function(data) {


        uploads(id);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Failed! " + data.error);
    }
});​
```

Comment: this is making call to success function but not posting image to facebook(no data is sent to facebook)

Comment: @BadalSurana this is not the problem with post, check that you send that data in correct format that FB want..

Comment: it is working fine with `dataType: "json"` in chrome but with `dataType: "jsonp"` its not working.

Comment: @Shaheer don't understand.. explain pls

Comment: @thecodeparadox adding jsonCallback did nothing. still not working.

Comment: @BadalSurana you might have been using the updated coded with dataType: "jsonp" please post that updated code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

> Whats wrong in this code?

Wrong question :-)

Right question: Why are you trying to do this yourself via AJAX – instead of just using the JS SDK and call it’s API method?

That will take care of everything for you.